# Naming convention for human readable version of variable

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I have a class that has an integer property `difficulty`. The value is stored as a number between `1` and `3` and is displayed as `"Beginner"`, `"Intermediate"`, or `"Expert"`.

I have a method that converts the integer into one of these more human readable labels, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good name for the method. I prefixed `hr_` to the variable's name such as `hr_difficulty`, but I'm wondering if there's a better convention.

Comment: I am both pleased and surprised that no one has yet suggested something like: `map_1_to_beginner_2_to_intermediate_and_3_to_expert`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm new to Ruby. What would this accomplish?

Comment: I was poking fun at those in the audience who are members of the *School of Believers in Extraordinarily Long Names for Variables, Methods and Most Everything Else*. As you may have guessed, I did not matriculate at that prestigious institution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit well with other parts of the code, particularly how it would look like if it were a method call, I use affix, not prefix e.g., `difficulty_s`. This implies that you had `difficulty`, then did something to it, which corresponds to the `_s` part. `hr` or "human readable" sounds too specific to me. I think `s` for "string" is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a generic method with this signature:

```
human_option_name(:difficulty)[difficulty]
```

Because you might need a list of all defficulties anyway (in select options for example) and you may need to include translations later on. That naming is analog to the already existing method [`human_attribute_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name)

Answer (score 0):

I think `difficulty_in_words` will be better as it naturally difficulty in words.